# Cannot ssh into created AMI on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, cloud, vmware

I have created a CentOS 6 AMI from a VMWare vmdk using the following commands:

```
$ec2-bundle-image -i CentOS_6.vmdk -r x86_64 -k ~/.ec2/pk.pem -c ~/.ec2/cert.pem --user <user_id>  
$ec2-upload-bundle -b <bucket_name> -m /tmp/CentOS_6.vmdk.manifest.xml -a <access_id> -s <secret_key>  
$ec2-register <bucket_name>/CentOS_6.vmdk.manifest.xml
```

I launched an instance after creation with m1.large storage. I am facing the following problems:

1. Instance Status Check fails.
2. Cannot ssh into the instance.

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try to ping to your instance, if there is reply then try to ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@public-DNS-of-ec2-instance. make sure you are in right folder where you download the ssh key.

Comment: you cal also use putty, but you need to generate a private key .ppk

Comment: "ssh: connect to host ec2-23-22-3-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out" is the error I get when I ssh into the instance..the same error message through putty.

Comment: Can you check the system log and see if something failed there at boot time?

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened up port 22 in the security group (i.e., firewall) that your instance is running with?

Answer (score -4):

AWS documentation usually has the answer you're looking for.

For complete list of documentation, please visit:

```
http://aws.amazon.com/documentation
```

For specific guides:

```
EC2 : http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/ec2
VPC: http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/vpc
S3: http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/s3/`enter code here`
```